# Generate specification plan of specs2 using Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, specs

I am having trouble outputting the specification plan of my specs2 specifications using Maven. I have, e.g.,

```
class FooTest extends SpecificationWithJUnit{
  "foo" should {
    "bar" in { "bat" must_== "bat" }
}
```

And want to have output of,

```
foo should
  + bar 
(...success messages...)
```

But all I can get is the JUnit-style

```
Running FooTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.797 sec
```

And my surefire plugin is configured as:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
  <configuration>
     <useFile>true</useFile>
     <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
     <includes>
       <include>**/*Test.*</include>
       <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
     </includes>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Is there a property I can set that will generate the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- use the [maven-scala](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/run-mojo.html) plugin to execute the specification with `specs2.run mypackage.MySpec` (details [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Console+output))
- use the [latest specs2 snapshot](http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/specs2/specs2_2.9.1.RC1/1.6-SNAPSHOT/), where you can pass system properties to display the results on the console as the JUnit runner executes the specification: `-Dspecs2.console`. In that mode you can pass additional command line arguments with `-Dspecs2.commandline=nocolor` (to remove ASCII colors from the output for example)

Comment: The second item is great! Thanks a lot for this feature.